# Получить документацию/коммент поля класса

Tags: .net, vb.net, рефлексия

Имеется класс с полями, у полей есть описание.

Пример

```
Public Class ElementBT3

    ''' <summary>
    ''' [Выравнивание]
    ''' Сдвинуть элемент влево
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public hasClassPullLeft As Boolean = False

End Class
```

Перебираю поля так

```
For Each fi As FieldInfo In obj.GetType().GetFields

Next
```

Вопрос, как получить текст комментария

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' [Выравнивание]
    ''' Сдвинуть элемент влево
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
```

**UPDATE**

Добавил атрибут

```
<Description("[Выравнивание] Сдвинуть элемент влево")> _
Public hasClassPullLeft As Boolean = False
```

Как теперь его достать?
В `Attributes` ничего нет, какое то странное значение `Public {6}`

Answer (score 3):

Если коротко - никак. XML комментарии не сохраняются в исходном коде. Однако, если очень хочется, есть несколько вариантов решения проблемы. Например можно на этапе сборки проекта формировать внешний файл, который будет содержать XML комментарии.
Либо если у вас есть доступ к исходникам(в рантайме), вы можете использовать Roslyn для извлечения комментариев.

Вот пример с Roslyn:

```
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
/// <summary>This is an xml doc comment</summary>
class C
{
}");
        var classNode = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)tree.GetRoot().Members.First();
        var trivia = classNode.GetLeadingTrivia().Single(t => t.Kind == SyntaxKind.DocumentationCommentTrivia);
        var xml = trivia.GetStructure();
        Console.WriteLine(xml);

        var compilation = Compilation.Create("test", syntaxTrees: new[] { tree });
        var classSymbol = compilation.GlobalNamespace.GetTypeMembers("C").Single();
        var docComment = classSymbol.GetDocumentationComment();
        Console.WriteLine(docComment.SummaryTextOpt);
    }
}
```

Как вариант попроще, можете использовать аттрибуты для хранения описания к методам:

```
[Display(Name = "Foo", Description = "Blah")]
void Foo()
{
}
```

Comment: Исходник есть, и речь про поля а не методы, добавил атрибут (обновил вопрос), но как достать атрибут этот, если это проще.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь исходник должен быть доступен в рантайме! Т.е вы должны обратиться из программы к исходнику как к текстовому файлу.

Comment: вы не правы или не поняли суть вопроса. Ответ выше.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь нет, я как раз таки прав. Во время компиляции комментарии попросту отсекаются, другими словами их больше нету. Что бы получить доступ к ним, вам нужно обеспечить их существование. Я вам описал 3 варианта. 3-й как раз это тоже самое, что вы написали в своем ответе(правда на C#, но разница только в синтаксисе)

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение вопроса для атрибута.

```
<Description("[Выравнивание] Сдвинуть элемент влево")> _
Public hasClassPullLeft As Boolean = False

For Each fi As FieldInfo In obj.GetType().GetFields
    Dim doc As System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute = fi.GetCustomAttributes(True)(0)
    Dim desc As String = doc.Description
Next
```